# UIKit file not found - Clion - Cocos2d-x

Tags: uikit, cocos2d-x, clion

I try to use Clion to run my cocos2d-x project. However...

```
/Users/aquarids/Documents/Project/Test/proj.ios_mac/ios/main.m:1:9: fatal 
In file included from         /Users/aquarids/Documents/Project/Test/proj.ios_mac/ios/AppController.mm
:25:
/Users/aquarids/Documents/Project/Test/proj.ios_mac/ios/AppController.h:1:9: fatal error: 'UIKit/UIKit.h' file not found
/Users/aquarids/Documents/Project/Test/proj.ios_mac/ios/RootViewController.mm:26:
/Users/aquarids/Documents/Project/Test/proj.ios_mac/ios/RootViewController.h:26:9: fatal error: 'UIKit/UIKit.h' file not found
```

How should I do?